# Nested Background workers, updating the UI from the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have two methods that need to be run async. In order for `Method B()` to run, it calls `Method A()`, but sometimes `Method A()` gets called elsewhere by itself. In the Background Worker completed event, I update the UI and everything is fine if `Method A()` was called from the main thread. However when `Method A()` gets called inside of `Method B()`, the `RunWorkerCompleted` for `Method A()` is now happening on `Method B()`'s thread instead of the main thread. The only solution I can think of would be to implement an event listener on the Main thread and then in `Method A()`'s `RunWorkerComplete` method, raise this event. Can anyone give me any insight on how to accomplish this, or if there are better ways to handle this issue?

Comment: *Don't* use BGWs, they are obsolete since .NET 4.5 came out back in 2012. One reason is that you *can't* combine or nest them. Use Task.Run, async/await etc and report progress through the `IProgress< T>` interface. Check [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: You have too many different options for this to be a good Stack Overflow question. It's just too broad, especially without a good [mcve] showing clearly your proposed solution. That said, `RunWorkerCompleted` translates to the continuation after `await` using the `async`/`await` paradigm, so IMHO the previous comment is the best guidance. You don't even need to mess with `Progress<T>` in this case (though it's a useful implementation of `IProgress<T>` in other scenarios).

Comment: @JacobAlley: [More information about upgrading from BGW to `Task.Run` is available on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

BGW is obsolete. *All* of its functionality has been replaced by `async/await`, Task.Run, the [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and [CancellationToken/CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). The .NET Blog post [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) shows how progres and cancellation work in managed threads and asynchronous APIs.

Given that the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2, you can be assured that `async/await` will always be available.

One of the reasons BGW is obsolete is that you just *can't* nest or combine BGWs. BGW was introduced in the first .NET versions to execute simple jobs in a form's background/ That's why it's part of `System.ComponentModel` and raises interfaces.

Creating a method that performs some heavy processing *and* calls a REST API asynchronously is trivial with `async/await` :

```
HttpClient _restClient=new HttpClient();

async Task MethodA(int someParam)
{
    toolStripLabel.Text ="Starting ...";
    var result=await Task.Run(()=>FunctionB(someParam));
    toolStripLabel.Text ="Calling ...";
    var response=await _restClient.GetAsync(${baseUrl}/{result}");
    toolStripLabel.Text ="Finished";        
    this.TextBox1.Text=response;
}
```

`Task.Run` will run `FunctionB` in a background thread. `await` releases the current, UI thread until the task generated by `Task.Run` completes. Once it does, execution returns to the UI thread. The UI can be modified directly.

Calling the asynchronous methods of HttpClient or any other asynchronous API does *not* run on a background thread - such IO operations are handled asynchronously at the OS level through IO completion ports - roughly callbacks that are called when an IO operation completes. The OS just doesn't block waiting for a disk or network response.

What if `FunctionB` runs so long that we need some progress reporting?

We can use a complex class to report progress or simply to send intermediate results to whoever is listening:

```
public class Report
{ 
    public string Message{get;set;}
    public string Status{get;set;}
    public int Progress{get;set;}
    //Why not?
    public Color MessageColor{get;set;}

    Report(string message,string status, int progress, Color color)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

In this case, `Progress<T>` will just call this method to update the UI and log any messages:

```
void ReportProgress(Report report)
{
    //Doesn't have to be UI only
    Log.Verbose(report.Message);
    toolStripLabel.Text =report.Status;
    toolStripLabel.BackColor=report.Color;
    toolStripProgress.Value=report.Progress;
}
```

`MethodA` itself can use `Progress< T>` to decouple itself from the UI:

```
async Task MethodA(int someParam)
{
    IProgress<Report> progress=new Progress<Report>(ReportProgress)
    progress.Report(new Report("Starting","Starting",0,Color.White);

    var result=await Task.Run(()=>FunctionB(someParam,progress));

    progress.Report(new Report("Calling API","Calling",95,Color.Aqua);

    var response=await _restClient.GetAsync(${baseUrl}/{result}");

    progress.Report(new Report("Finished progessing","Finished",100,Color.White);

    this.TextBox1.Text=response;
}
```

and `FunctionB` could report progress like this:

```
int FunctionB(int someParam,IProgress<Report> progress)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10000000; i++)
    {
        //Do the work and report
       if (i % 100000 ==0)
       {
           var value=(int)(i / 100000.0);
           progress.Report(new Report("Blah blah","Processing",value,Color.Pink);
       }
       progress.Report(new Report("Blah blah","Processing Finished",100,Color.Red);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also invoke the UI elements you need to update. This could look like this:

```
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { textBox1.Text = "TEST"; });
```

Comment: BGWs are used to *avoid* such tricks. Updating the UI should be perfromed through the ProgressChanged event

Comment: That might be true. Nevertheless, does my answer solve the problem. Design specific questions are answered in another Stackexchange subforum

Comment: No it doesn't. It breaks the usage pattern of BGW. This isn't about design it's about *misusing* the BGW class

Comment: _"does my answer solve the problem"_ -- no, not really. It doesn't address the _question_ that was posted. The OP is almost certainly aware that they _could_ use `Control.Invoke()` to get back to the UI thread. The point here is to use `BackgroundWorker` or some similar mechanism to do so implicitly, i.e. to take advantage of the existing features to avoid complicating the code with explicit calls to `Control.Invoke()`.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the compiler error or runtime error this gives you? Exactly: none. If it's stupid and works ....

Comment: And it *causes harm*. Calling `Invoke` can easily lead to deadlock if the UI thread is busy - possibly because another BGW is calling it

Comment: @RomanoZumbé it doesn't work and I just explained why. BGW provides a mechanism for this to *actually* work, since it was introduced in the 2000s.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé before you say "that doesn't happen" search SO for UI deadlock questions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is simply not true. Despite the fact, thatit is no good style and clearly not what is intended by the designers of the BackgroundWorker class, it DOES work!

Comment: I do believe you that this can lead to problems. But it's nothing else than with other Threads. BackgroundWorker is just a simplified callback mechanism

Comment: @RomanoZumbé and `catch {}` does work. Until it doesn't. It's not a matter of style. BTW *BeginInvoke*. There just is no argument that can justify the use of `Invoke`